# SQL Server Table-Valued Parameters in c++ OLEDB client?

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb

I have an c++ application working ith SQL Server via OLEDB. 
How to use table-valued parameters in old good unmanaged c++ OLEDB clients?

In NET app it is clear how to :

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Customers", dataTable);
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;           
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            // Execute the command
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

How to pass this kind of parameters calling stored procedures in c++ oledb client app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of doing it using ADO, is that what you're looking for? http://msftdpprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008%21Readme_Table-Valued%20Parameters&referringTitle=Home